# Can not add .gpx to Xcode to simulate location changes

Tags: xcode, gpx

I can not add .gpx files to xcode. I know that xcode takes specific .gpx with , but nothing works for me.

What I've tried:

1.

```
<gpx>
<wpt lat="52.529985" lon="13.403">
</wpt>
<wpt lat="52.529976" lon="13.403069">
</wpt>
```

2.
Adding google routes/gps points here:
https://labs.coruscantconsulting.co.uk/garmin/gpxgmap/mobiledev.php
http://www.bikehike.co.uk/mapview.php

When I try to add .gpx to Debug/Simulate Location/Add GPX... or in Product/Scheme.../Add GPX, my .gpx files are always greyout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your gpx file is missing some parts, try creating a file at [GPX Generator](https://www.gpxgenerator.com) and compare it with your own.